# INSERT error - Implicit conversion of varchar value (collation)

Tags: sql, collation

When I try to change my stored procedure (below) and I receive this error message:

"Implicit conversion of varchar value to varchar cannot be performed because the collation of the value is unresolved due to a collation conflict"

The error occurs in this line:

```
INSERT INTO @TempList (OrderID) VALUES (@EmpID)
```

I don´t understand what problem with collation exist.

Please, ideas about this..

Thanks

```
USE [database]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON

GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[database_0301_PRJ_dir_ger]

@EmpList varchar(100)

AS

  DECLARE @TempList table (OrderID varchar(10))
  DECLARE @EmpID varchar(10) 
  DECLARE @Pos int

  IF @EmpList <> ''
  BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    SET @EmpList = LTRIM(RTRIM(@EmpList))+ ','
    SET @Pos = CHARINDEX(',', @EmpList, 1)

    IF REPLACE(@EmpList, ',', '') <> ''
    BEGIN
      WHILE @Pos > 0
      BEGIN
        SET @EmpID = LTRIM(RTRIM(LEFT(@EmpList, @Pos - 1)))
        IF @EmpID <> ''
        BEGIN
          INSERT INTO @TempList (OrderID) VALUES (@EmpID)
        END
        SET @EmpList = RIGHT(@EmpList, LEN(@EmpList) - @Pos)
        SET @Pos = CHARINDEX(',', @EmpList, 1)
      END
  END

  SELECT dir.sigla + '-' + ger.nome AS dirger, 
    ger.codigo as gercodigo, 
    ger.nome as gernome, 
    dir.nome AS dirnome, 
    ger.diretoria as gerdiretoria 
  FROM d
    bo.database_091500_GERENCIAS AS ger 
  INNER JOIN 
    dbo.database_090200_DIRETORIAS AS dir 
  ON 
    ger.diretoria = dir.codigo 
  WHERE 
    ger.diretoria IN (select * FROM @TempList)
END
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like a configuration problem with language/internationalization.

Perhaps your client might be configured for one locale, and your database/database server for a different locale?

One workaround might be an explicit cast, for example:

http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic225939-8-1.aspx#bm225952